# Reverse a linked list in a pair in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, reverse

I'm studying data structure in Java.

I have a linked list:

`1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5`

And I'd like to reverse the linked list, but in a pair.

`2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 5`

I wrote a code, but it doesn't work

```
private void reversePair(Node headNode) {
    Node tempNode1 = null;
    Node tempNode2 = null;
    Node currentNode = headNode;

    while(currentNode != null && currentNode.getNext() != null) {
        tempNode1 = currentNode.getNext();
        tempNode2 = tempNode1.getNext();

        tempNode1.setNext(currentNode);
        currentNode.setNext(tempNode2);

        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }
}
```

It became `1 -> 3 -> 5`, and I don't know what's the logic hole here.

Could you explain what's the problem in my code and the solution?

Comment: If you step through this with a debugger, you will see immediately what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, I already did, I'm kinda get it, but I don't know how to fix this

Comment: So maybe when you swap two nodes, you need to keep a reference to one of them, so that when you come to swap the next two, you can call `setNext` on the one that you've kept the reference to.

Comment: You can't do this without changing the contents of (or returning a reference to) the first node in a list. You enter this method with a value-copy of the reference to Node(1), and nothing (absolutely nothing) will change this reference's pointing to the Node object containing 1. So, no matter what @DavidWallace suggests, your approach is impossible unless you *return* the *new* link to the Node(2) and the caller of reversePair uses this to update the List node. -- As an alternative, consider swapping the *values* stored in Node(1) and Node(2) without fiddling with setNext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problem inside your code. The first one is that the node that you pass to the method doesn't change outside the method, it still point to 1!
The second problem is inside the while loop... you do something like

temp1->2, temp2->3 after that 2->1 and 1->3 at the end of the while you obtain

2->1->3->4->....
that is ok
But now:

1) as I said headNode, outside the method, point to 1, so it see the list as 
1->3->4->...

2) the next while iteration swap 3 and 4 (4->3,3->5), but 1 still point to 3, it doesn't change! So the headNode outside the method see the list as 1->3->5->...

Fixing the second problem should be easy. The first one is more difficult, I suggest to save 2 ( the new head) and return it as the new head. It's not elegant, you have to call the method as `headNode = reversePair(headNode)` but it should work.